# Render a view of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I want to do is have 2 different controllers, client and test_client.  The client controller is already built and I want to create a test_client controller that i can use to play around with the UI of the client and adjust it as needed.  I am mainly trying to get around the validation i have built into the client and its dependence on an admin controller that loads the data.

so i want the test_client controller to load a sample data set and then render the client controller's index view so i can adjust the clients UI.  That is all.

I tried this in the test_clients index method:

```
class TestClient
    def index
        render :template => 'client/index'
    end
end
```

but i get an error because it cannot find the client partials as it is looking in the current controllers view for them...

So I have looked into this already and most people say that you should never make such a call but i think that this case is a reasonable usage...I just need to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Are you using git? Because this is a nice use-case for git branches IMHO.

Comment: I am actually using svn but that is a good idea.  I might try that on my next project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to adjust your view so that the path to the partial you need is in the form `'controller/partial'`.  In this case probably `'client/partial'`.  Then you can simply use `render 'client/index'` as before.

So say somewhere in your view you have this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'info' %>
```

You will want to change it to this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'client/info' %>
```

Comment: this solution worked fine even though I am not a huge fan of having the controller hard coded in there its not going to effect anything for me unless i rename the controller.

Comment: If this is a partial used in multiple controllers, I usually put them under `app/views/shared`, then you do `render :partial => 'shared/info'` or something similar.  Might want to name it better then.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your client controller views to partials, create empty views for all actions in test_client controller, render client partials for respective test_client views.

Example:
client view
index.html.erb to _index.html.erb

test_client view
index.html.erb
 in this view, <%=render :partial => 'clients/index', :locals =>{ }%>

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a number of ways and everyone is different. One way you could do it, is by putting your finders into a presenter. Then turn some data in the index view into a partial or you can render the template with layout set to false.

Then in the client_test view you can render that index with the presenter associated with it.